# What does this weird lambda C# operator do?

Tags: c#, lambda

Looking at some source code, I found this operator

```
() => { }
```

From reading MSDN I now know it is the lambda operator, but what effect will it have on () going through { }? It is used as an argument to a class constructor.

Comment: () will become arguments to the function contained in { }.  What, specifically, do you need to know?

Comment: That is the curlify-parenthasis operator. It makes the code look fancier. It was invented by computing pioneers back in the Baroque Period. :D

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is an `Action` (void, no parameters) delegate with a body that does nothing. Useful for when a non-null delegate is needed (perhaps to simplify callback or event invocation, as invoking on a `null` is an error), but you have nothing specific to do.

Comment: Great thanks, I see how that works now. I'm guessing they are used for kind of the same purpose as a function pointer in C/C++?

Comment: @Tanner you mean delegates in general? Pretty much, yes - but delegates offer more type safety, access to meta (the MethodInfo), and automatic multicast capability.

Comment: ♦ I think main difference of delegates that they carry object context with them.

Comment: @Andrey it at least *can*; there are even some evil tricks you can do there to use an unbound delegate to call instance methods.

Answer (score 7):

It can be called empty delegate. It does nothing, but it is safe to call it without checking for `null`s. Sort of placeholder.

I use it like this:

```
    event Action SafeEvent = () => { };

    event Action NullableEvent;        

    void Meth()
    {
        //Always ok
        SafeEvent();

        //Not safe
        NullableEvent();

        //Safe
        if (NullableEvent != null)
            NullableEvent();
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

It's for a parameter of Action in the constructor probably. By doing `() => { }` that gives the object a valid Action to execute that doesn't do anything when called.

Answer (score 3):

() parameter list

=> lambda invocation

{} scope of executed code (optional, if it's a one-liner)

Answer (score 2):

That might help you to understand more clearly...

> () => { }

is equivalent to

> function() {  }

another example:

> (i) => { i += 1; }

is equivalent to

> function(int i) { i += 1; }